# Can't submit form, submit button not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have created a form and inside the form is a table. However, I am unable to submit the form to the processing page as submit button gives no response at all. After clicking the submit button, nothing happens.

The following is my code

http://pastebin.com/tPMq7GmU

Thank you very much for helping me!

The following code is the problem which makes the submit button to not work.

```
<input type="text" name="schoolname" id="schoolid" placeholder="Please Specify" required style='display:none;'/>
```

The submit button works if I removed the above code.

The function of the above code is to pop out a text field when the "others" value is selected in .

Here is the full code of the function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function CheckSchoolName(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('schoolid');
 if(val=='otherschool')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script>
```

Below is the code inside the table for my form.

```
<tr>
<td>NAME OF SCHOOL</td>
<td>        
<select name="schoolname" onchange='CheckSchoolName(this.value);'>
<option value="">Select your Instituition/School name</option>
        <option value="Caritas Bianchi College of Careers">Caritas Bianchi College of Careers</option>
        <option value="Caritas Francis Hsu College">Caritas Francis Hsu College</option>
        <option value="otherschool">Others (Please specify)</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text" name="schoolname" id="schoolid" placeholder="Please Specify" required style='display:none;'/>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post relevant code in question, thx!

Comment: and use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum that displays the issue and post it here. Linking to 2,200 lines elsewhere shows zero effort on your behalf.

Comment: My bad,I have found the problem but cant fix unless I remove that part of code. I have posted it above, you may take a look. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably being caused by the `required` attribute used in

```
<input type="text" name="schoolname" id="schoolid" placeholder="Please Specify" required  style='display:none;'/>
```

This requires the input field to contain a value before the form can be submitted, since the display is set to none this will obviously conflict. Remove the `required` attribute and give it another go

Answer (score 0):

The rule:

```
display: none
```

could give you some problems.
I suggest you to set the tag:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="schoolname" 
       id="schoolid" 
       placeholder="Please Specify"
       required 
       value="" />
```

then change the CheckSchoolName function like this:

```
function CheckSchoolName(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('schoolid');
  if(val=='otherschool')
     element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
}
```